# Two DataFrames Random Sample by Day grouping instead of hour

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

I have two dataframes, One is Price and the other one is Volume. They are both hourly and for the the same timeframe (one year).

```
dfP = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, 10, (8760,4)), index=pd.date_range('2008-01-01', periods=8760, freq='H'), columns='Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4'.split())
dfV = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(50, 100, (8760,4)), index=pd.date_range('2008-01-01', periods=8760, freq='H'), columns='Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4'.split())
```

Each Day is a SET in the sense that the values have to stay together. When a sample is generated, it needs to be a full day. so a sample would be (for example 24 hours of Feb 2, 2008) in this data set. I would like to generate a 185 day (50%) sample set for dfP and have the Volumes from the same days so i can generate a sum product.

```
dfProduct = dfP_Sample * dfV_Sample
```

I am lost on how to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're expecting to get the sum of the  volumes and prices for each day and then multiply them together?

If that's the case, try the following.  If not, please clarify your question.

```
priceGroup = dfP.groupby(by=dfP.index.date).sum()
volumeGroup = dfV.grouby(by=dfV.index.date).sum()
dfProduct = priceGroup*volumeGroup
```

If you want to just look at a specific date range,  try

```
import datetime as datetime    
dfProduct[np.logical_and(dfProduct.index > datetime.date(2006,08,09),dfProduct.index < datetime.date(2007,01,02))]
```

Comment: the OP wants to take sample of year days , this is not the right answer , read the question again

Answer (score 0):

First of all we'll generate a column that refers to the day index of the year for example `2008-01-01` will be assigned 1 because it indicates first day of the year and so on

```
day_order = [date.timetuple().tm_yday for date in dfP.index]

dfP['day_order'] = day_order
```

then generate random days from 1 to 365 this will represent the day order in the year for example if you get random number `1` this indicates `2008-01-01`

```
random_days = np.random.choice(np.arange(1 , 366) , size = 185 , replace=False)
```

then slice your original data frame to get only values from random sample according to the day order column we've created previously

```
dfP_sample = dfP[dfP.day_order.isin(random_days)]
```

then you can merge both frames on index , and you can do whatever you want

```
final = pd.merge(dfP_sample , dfV , left_index=True , right_index=True)

final.head()
Out[47]:
                        Col1_x  Col2_x  Col3_x  Col4_x  day_order   Col1_y  Col2_y  Col3_y  Col4_y
    2008-01-03 00:00:00 9       6       9       9       3           66      85      62      82
    2008-01-03 01:00:00 5       8       9       8       3           54      89      65      98
    2008-01-03 02:00:00 7       5       5       9       3           83      58      60      96
    2008-01-03 03:00:00 9       5       7       6       3           59      54      67      78
    2008-01-03 04:00:00 9       5       8       9       3           92      66      66      55
```

if you don't want to merge both frames , you can apply the same logic on `dfV`
and then you will get samples from both data frames on the same days